# GoPro4: Color shifts in video

Tags: video

I'm not sure where to put this question, but I think signal processing section is the best section to ask.

So I am having a problem with my camera, apparently the filter color shifts to purple, then green, then back to normal while recording. The camera also showed many grains despite the 1080p resolution. 
Is there something wrong with the Image Processing Unit? Should I replace it? I don't think it's lens problem though. I just replaced the motherboard but it didn't solve the problem. Btw, the camera has fell over from a car once and is out of warranty.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post a link to a clip showing the issue? It's hard to diagnose without seeing the actual problem.

Comment: I've seen something similar once. After a point-and-shoot camera got wet.

Comment: I can't upload my photo right now, but it should look similar to [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YWZmr.jpg).